# Indexing database queries for reporting purposes

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that stores data for all parts that are produced on a assembly line, there where about 1 million parts produced, each one with lets say 200 entries. The customer wants me to do several queries to get some informations about how production is going.

Some of these are really complex queries that require to analyse if this part was faulted during assembly and whether that fault was corrected or not. This will take some significant time done for a week of data.

OK, the queries can surely be optimized but that is not what I am looking for at this point.

My idea is to index this reporting queries. I use already an asynchrounos job to save gathered data into the correct database schema. It must be possible to extend this job and save this data into prepared formatted tables to query from. The user will get his report with about 30 seconds delay, but it should be ultra-fast.

So can I use SQL Server Reporting Services to define an indexing job and query against it?
Or is there any other tool that will do that job?

Comment: This is not an objective question.  Yes, of course you can use SSRS for generating reports.  You can also do whatever 'asynchronous' job you're using (whatever that means).  You can write a sproc that stores data to hourly tables, then the user just queries against that.

Comment: But can I automate generating reports with SSRS and access it from within my application? I would only prefer writing my own stored procedure to fill tables when there is no tool that could do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into SSRS report snapshots and history.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630404.aspx

You would then access the report using one of the SSRS access methods.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153697.aspx

The snapshots will run your report ahead off hours.  You would then display one of these snapshots in your application.